# TypeScript: Type checking while parsing an arbitrary JSON that is typed/

Tags: json, typescript, parsing, typechecking

```js
type KeyValueWrapperTypeObject = {
  [key: string]: Wrapper<unknown>,
}

type KeyValueUnknownTypeObject = {
  [key: string]: unknown,
}

type MyDeterminedTypedObject = {
  key1: Wrapper<string>,
  key2: Wrapper<number>,
  key3: Wrapper<{
    nestedKey: boolean,
  }>
}

type ConvertValueTypesOfMappedTypeToSpecifiedType<MappedType, SpecifiedType> = {
  [K in keyof MappedType]: SpecifiedType;
};

class Wrapper<T> {
  #t: T

  constructor(t: T) {
    this.#t = t
  }

  reveal(): T {
    return this.#t
  }
}

function makeKeyValueWrapperObjectFromJson<S extends KeyValueWrapperTypeObject>(json: string): S {
  const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
  const result: any = {};

  for (const key in parsedJson) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedJson, key)) {
      result[key] = new Wrapper(parsedJson[key]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const jsonString = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "123", "key3": {"nestedKey": true}}';

const keyValueWrapperObject = makeKeyValueWrapperObjectFromJson<MyDeterminedTypedObject>(jsonString);

console.log(keyValueWrapperObject.key1.reveal());
console.log(keyValueWrapperObject.key2.reveal()); // how to type check this?
console.log(keyValueWrapperObject.key3.reveal().nestedKey);
```

I am trying to wrap all the values of an arbitrary object with `Wrapper<T>`.

The function `makeKeyValueWrapperObjectFromJson`, first parses a JSON string, then given that parsed TypeScript object, it looks through all its values, construct a new `Wrapper<T>` and setting it as the value corresponding to the key of the object as typed by `MyDeterminedTypedObject`.

`key2` is supposed to be of type `number` but the JSON string has it as `"123"` which is parsed as string.

Is there anyway to write `makeKeyValueWrapperObjectFromJson`, such that it is able to create arbitrary instances of any tips just by 'inspecting' the type argument `MyDeterminedTypedObject` passed into the type parameter of the function?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-7ePkLzxC9ud4A8eDSdzjTSkx3JS8Fmc5zfEBpCbR8oGMDgIg4LUdT1Z8uxxCIx3oJM9geNMpHcAByZgACISjwgQ8P2SMIGKPD-gI+AGiIqA8OKBpeko+jvGYgR8PGSYMmmOiRAwQxDGwvEULhSwyOjZI43ca1bXE6xJOwOM3Q9OcvniRJkjScZQQyOMEzQ8QMP8SQwPxFkFggCUUHUSROW8e1FNXEoJUVZUL3vHEx0s6zbPs+So1-JSqDyCVGlcpUlg8psoAAeliqARS0YV1GFKIaBFWhuH1cUAH5zJzHybLshyJKC5y+gi9zVQlLikh4+AwKAA)